# Reading multiple child nodes from Firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a collection view where I am attempting to append the information that the user has uploaded. Currently my database looks as followed:
[image]

I am attempting to get the titles, audioURl, Description, image, etc. & append them into my array. The problem is I am getting a crash every time I try to do it. I am relatively new to Firebase & still learning as I go.

Currently my code for retrieving is as followed:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("uploads").child("allUploads")

        ref.observe(.value, with: {(snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in

            print(snap)

            let track = TracksInfo()
            let snapshotDictionnary = snap.value! as? [String: AnyObject]


            track.trackName = snapshotDictionnary?["Title"] as! String
            track.urlToRecording = snapshotDictionnary?["audioUrl"] as! String
            track.urlToAlbumArtWork = snapshotDictionnary?["imageUrl"] as! String

            self.tracks.append(track)

        })
```

How would I go about accessing each of the uploads information & append them into my array? Do I need to do a query of some sort?

My Crash occurs @  `track.trackName = snapshotDictionnary?["Title"] as! String` But there is no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over *all* those uploads nodes. Your current code is handling the complete `allUploads` nodes at once ;) As such, you need to descend one level to get the information you want.

One quick way to do that, is observing `.childAdded` instead of `.value`. For instance:

```
ref.observe(.childAdded, with: {(snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
    ...
})
```

By the way, if you only want to read the data *once*, using `observeSingleEvent` might be a better fit here.

Comment: Would I still be using a loop in addition to this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `snap` object is itself a *collection* of child snapshots, so it doesn't have elements like "Title" and "audioURL". Its children do, however. So you probably want something more like this:

```
ref.observe(.value, with: {(snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in

  print(snap)
  for child in snap.children {
    if let child = child as? FIRDataSnapshot {
      let track = TracksInfo()
      let snapshotDictionnary = child.value! as? [String: AnyObject]
      track.trackName = snapshotDictionnary?["Title"] as! String
      // etc...
      self.tracks.append(track)
    }
  }
})
```

Paulo's suggestion works, too. Within the `.childAdded` event, you'll get the individual children instead of the collection of snapshots.

Comment: `print(track.trackName = snapshotDictionnary?["Title"] as! String)` Any Idea why this would be coming out as blank, when there is a value called "Test Totle"